# Object is not being added to a list, list returns empty

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, jsoup

I am retrieving data from a website and when I retrieve the data (String) then I get the display of countries

```java
for (Element row : document.select("table.sortable.wikitable tr")) {

                if (row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("")) {
                    continue;

                }
else {
String name = row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text();
System.out.println(name);

}
```

this gives me the list of countries in my console, now that I have verified that I am getting the countries I want to insert each country into a separate country object using a list

```java
final String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states";
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            for (Element row : document.select("table.sortable.wikitable tr")) {

                if (row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("")) {
                    continue;

                } else {
                    for (Country country : countries) {

                        country.setCountry(row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text());


                        countries.add(country);

                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(countries);
        }
```

when I print the list the list is null

```java
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
else {
    for (Country country : countries) {
        country.setCountry(row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text());
        countries.add(country);
    }
}
```

Think about what the code is doing.  When you hit your `else` block, you loop through your list of countries, and . . . create a new country as many times as there are existing countries in your list.  But since the list starts as empty, that loop will never execute.

The solution is simple.  Get rid of the loop entirely, and just do this:

```
else {
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setCountry(row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text());
    countries.add(country);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `Country country : countries` where you want to add a new country to the list, `countries` by default contains no values therefore it will loop through a list with 0 values and do nothing. You're not yet adding new countries to your `countries` list anywhere.

You probably meant to do something like this, where you're creating a new instance of `Country`:

```
if (row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("")) {
    continue;
} else {
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName(row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text());
    countries.add(country);
}
```

(above code is assuming `td:nth-of-type(1)` contains the country name but is just merely an example)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the list of countries and not creating a new `Country` object. 
As our colleagues mention, you should first create the instance of your `Country` object, set its fields and then include in the list. I would expand the example and move the country name to it's constructor to prevent null pointers.

```java
else {
    String countryName = row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text();
    Country country = new Country(countryName);
    countries.add(country);
}
```